# core-0.13.0.job.jar is missing and i need it

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

I need to use this core folder in my example

hadoop jar $MAHOUT_HOME/core/target/mahout-core-xyz.job.jar

org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe

-p /user/hue/KDDTrain/KDDTrain+_20Percent.arff -f /user/hue/KDDTrain/KDDTrain+.info -d N 3 C 2 N C 4 N C 8 N 2 C 19 N L
but i have Mahout-0.13.0 and there is no core folder. Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `mahout-core-xyz.jar` in Mahout 0.13.0. As of Mahout 0.10.0 This module (`core`) and it's corresponding jar (`mahout-core-xyz.jar`) has been renamed to Map Reduce Legacy and the jar: `mahout-mr-0.13.x.jar`.

As well while this code  is no longer supported and having been deprecated in 2014.

Comment: can you explain how can i use it in the previous example please?

Comment: Also , I could not find this" org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe" in Mahout folder

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your command to the following:

```
hadoop jar $MAHOUT_HOME/mahout-mr-0.13.0-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe -p pathToYourData/KDDTrain+.arff -f pathToOutputInfo/KDDTrain+.info -d N 3 C 2 N C 4 N C 8 N 2 C 19 N L
```

Note that you need to change 'pathToYourData' and 'pathToOutputInfo' according to the way you did.